A countryside man runs to a city, we follow his path as he becomes sicker and sicker. At town he falls dead. Next we learn his disease killed everyone
I want to read fantasy book again that I read 15 years ago, but I forgot its title.
On chapter 1, we are following a countryside man (a farmer)
running to a city that is far away, for a purpose that I'm not sure is clear, maybe he wants to warn the city against something.
He is not aware of that at the beginning, but he is sick.
As he runs, his sickness increases. When he enters the town, he falls dead inside.
The first lines of chapter 2, inform us that this city holds no resident anymore: everyone has died by his disease.

@Marc Le Bihan can you elaborate on what fantasy elements are there in this book?

It's at least reminiscent of Zelazny's To Die in Italbar.  https://archive.org/details/todieinitalbar0000zela/mode/2up

@AndresF. I'm sorry, I can't. I would like to read again that book because I remember that it pleased me, but I only remember its beginning just like I posted it.

@MarcLeBihan but how can you be sure it's a fantasy book if you won't name at least one element that is fantastic about it? It would help save this question from closure & deletion...

It sounds like a section of David Eddings' Malloreon, where a sailor enters Mal Zeth carrying the plague and wipes out half the town. That won't be it though, not enough details match.

@AndresF. If the questioner is confident that the work was fantasy or SF, then the question is on topic.

@AndresF. It sure sounds like a disease that doesn't exist to me, which ought to make it science fiction.

@Moriarty It's possible, because I've once red this book

@Buzz I don't think that's enough, sorry. There must be some evidence the question is actually about a work of fantasy, which should be trivial to provide (by the way: do not delete my comments but leave your part of the conversation; either delete everything or do not delete anything. Otherwise it seems petty.).

@AndresF. My book was in a fantasy world.

Might be a trope because it's also reminiscent of Stephen King's "The Stand" (person escaping from a disease laboratory which is shutting down because a disease has escaped, then accidentally infecting the whole town/city/world that he dies in). "The Stand" doesn't start with a man physically "running", though - he's in a car.
